# How to fetch between a range of indexes in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need help.. Is there any method available to fetch documents between a range of indexes while using find in mongo.. Like [2:10] (from 2 to 10)  ?

Comment: Do you mean the "index" of documents in a collection or the index position of an array field within your documents?

Comment: Array field actually.. Fetch only 2 to 10 from the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about the "index" position within an array in your document then you want the [**`$slice`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) operator. The first argument being the index to start with and the second is how many to return. So from a 0 index position 2 is the "third" index:

```
 db.collection.find({},{ "list": { "$slice": [ 2, 8 ] })
```

Within a collection itself if you use the [`.limit()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/) an [`.skip()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/) modifiers to move through the range in the collection:

```
db.collection.find({}).skip(2).limit(8)
```

Keep in mind that in the collection context MongoDB has no concept of "ordered" records and is dependent on the query and/or sort order that is given